# Creating a Protoype LDAP environment

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I'm training myself on developing with LDAP. Is there a specific opensource LDAP provider I can install on my local Windows machine to do this? The easier the better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://www.zytrax.com/books/ldap/ch4/win2k.html

> If you want to deploy an Open Source LDAPv3 compliant server in
>   Windows (XP, Windows 7, Vista) you have three choices:
>
> 1. **OpenLDAP under cygwin**. The cygwin installer has done a great job in making the installation a
>      long-winded but very simple process (it can take upwards of 30+ mins
>      to get everything installed) and they have done a terrific job of
>      hiding OpenLDAP (it's under the Libs category in the installer). The
>      major downside is that the OpenLDAP version may not be updated
>      regularly. If you are going to do development, or run other *nix
>      packages under Windows this is the obvious choice.
>      http://www.cygwin.com/
> 2. **ApacheDS**. Runs under Java and includes a great LDAP Client/Development
>      system called Apache Directory Studio. Superb tool as a client to any
>      system including OpenLDAP. Perhaps a tad complicated to install since
>      it's embedded into the Eclipse development environment (which always
>      likes to complicate things) but well worth the effort. http://directory.apache.org/apacheds/
> 3. If you want a simple, single click installation of the current version
>      of **OpenLDAP on Windows** then you can do no better than OpenLDAP for
>      Windows. It is updated pretty frequently (OpenLDAP 2.4.35 July 2013).
>      It installs Berkley DB (OpenLDAPs database bdb or database hdb),
>      OpenSSL (provides OpenLDAP TLS support) and even Cyrus SASL (provides
>      Kerberos support). We describe its installation below. OpenLDAP does
>      not run as a Windows task but rather runs inside a dos box. http://userbooster.de/en/download/openldap-for-windows.aspx

Comment: It looks like OpenLDAP on Windows may be what I'm looking for. I just need a prototype LDAP system to develop under.